# How to create a subscription topic in AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-moisture-create-sns-topic.html), how to create a SNS topic?  For me, when I use the AWS IoT page, I do not see a **Services** button.  [Here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=us-east-1#/home) is the IoT console link.

For context, I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://www.awsdeeplens.recipes/300_intermediate/310_worker_safety/314_set_up_ui/) in order to perform the second tutorial using the deeplens camera.  For ease of use, attached is the screenshot of the AWS IoT page that I see and the AWS DeepLens page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is just wrong. You create an SNS topic and subscription in the [SNS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v3/home?region=us-east-1#) console, not in the IOT console.

After you have done that, then you can specify your SNS topic as a target by an IOT rule, [the guide continues on here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-moisture-create-rule.html)

I'm going to file a [pull request](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-iot-docs/pull/35) to fix the docs in aws, they are wrong.